# how to put the form content into database and give back a php response?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have created a html form which sends certain variables to a php file, the file is saved in the database and returns the success through json back to the javascript. But the problem is am not able to save the data and get the response back to the javascript file. I donno what is the reason. So can some help me with this. Thank you

my form is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js">       </script>
<script src="scriptj.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost/donotdel/process.php" method="POST">
    <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my javascript file is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        $('.help-block').remove();
        var formData = {
            'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'email': $('input[name=email]').val(),
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/donotdel/process.php',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (!data.success) {
                if (data.errors.name) {
                    $('#name-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#name-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.name + '</div>');
                }

                if (data.errors.email) {
                    $('#email-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#email-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + '</div>');
                }
            }
            else {
                $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');
            }
        }).fail(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

and my php file is

```
<?php

$errors         = array();      
$data           = array(); 

if (empty($_POST['name']))
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';

if (empty($_POST['email']))
    $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';

if ( ! empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';
}
header ('Content-Type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

now from the above php file i want to enter the **name** and **email** into the database. but i donno how to do it. So can someone help me out with the code. and after entering i want to send the above json response back to the javascript

thank you

Comment: This should cover everything http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: are you using `mysqli` or `PDO `?

Comment: i can help you in inserting data that sit...is it ok

Comment: Sorry I just updated my answer to have some more useful code.  Everything should work out of box as soon as you fill in the variables.  ServerName, UserName, Password, and the QryString

Comment: @mudassar i want to enter the data into database and send a json response back to the above javascript file

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is establish a database connection and use that database connection to insert a new row in the users table.  If the sql errors out return the error, if it works return the json data.  Make sure to close the connection to the database when you are done.

**Start by building a dbconfig.php file**
This is used to establish the connection to your database.
This is what a simple one looks like.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "temppass";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

**Include the dbcong.php in your file**

```
include ('dbconfig.php');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    //if it make a connection insert code here!
    $qry = "INSERT ..."; //build your insert string here!
    $conn->query($qry); // run your insert here!
    //Don't forget to CLOSE YOUR CONNECTION!
    $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: this answer would be better it you used `->prepare()`, `->bind_param()`, and `->execute()` instead of `->query()`

Comment: The code was quickly writen for a persons first introduction to a mysql connection and insert.  I do apologize by bruit code but it is sufficient for learning purposes.  Please feel free to edit it to make it better.

Comment: yea i know this method of entering data but the problem that i am facing is i want to receive the data, enter into database using mysql and once successful want to send a json response to my javascript file which will be redirecting to another page. But here i am not able to enter the variables into database and send response only.

Comment: If you are giving `a persons first introduction to a mysql connection and insert` it is probably not a good idea to teach them bad methods that open them up to sql injection.

Comment: @SusanWilliams so what is your issue? You say you want to `receive the data, insert the data, and send a response`. Your code provided does all but `insert the data`, so it is logical for @SariRahal to assume you needed help inserting the data. So if that is not what you need help with, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @sean i tried wat srirahal had send but i could never get a response due to it

Comment: i wanted help in where to include srirahals code in order to enter the data into db and at the same time get the response also

Comment: Does the query to place in the $qry work?  Does it insert into the database?